# How can I remove a gap between a slider image and a simple sidebar when opened?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a simple sidebar for a menu, along with a slider.
The slider and the sidebar are functioning properly until I click 
the cursor to open the sidebar navigation.  The site is here: 
http://newlifecorpus.com/demo/example.html

As you can see a gap occurs between the slider image and the sidebar.
How can I fix this?  I am having a difficult time debugging this.
Please help.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div>
        <!--start-->
        <div id='ninja-slider'>
            <ul>
                <li><a data-image="images/test2.jpg"
                       href="http://www.menucool.com/responsive-slider">
                    <h3>The responsive image slider-1</h3></a></li>
                <li><div data-image="images/test3.jpg"><h3>test this</h3></div>
                </li>
                <li><div data-image="images/test4.jpg">
                    <h3>Mobile friendly / Touch-enabled-3</h3></div></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!--end-->
    </div>

</div><!-- end main wrapper-->

<---according to author, top bar and side bar logic must be
outside of main wrapper     -->

<div id="top-bar">
    <div id="menu-icon" class="menu-right">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 4 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 5 </a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 6 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 7 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 8 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 8 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 10 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ninja-slider
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto; /*center aligned*/
    background:#222;
}
#ninja-slider > ul
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

/* slide */
#ninja-slider li > div, #ninja-slider li > a
{
    /*max-width:960px;*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center each slide */
    /*border-radius:6px;
    background:#333;*/
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8),
    inset 0 0 1px   rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    transition:none!important;
}

/* loading image indicator */
#ninja-slider div.preload
{
    background: black url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center 25%;
}

/*----- video -----*/
#ninja-slider a.video
{
    position:absolute;
    border:0;top:0;left:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
    background:transparent url(images/video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    transition:none!important;
}

/*------ pager ------*/
/* The pager id should be: slider id + "-pager" */
#ninja-slider-pager
{
    display:none;
}

/* --------- navigation controls ------- */
/* The nav id should be: slider id + ("-prev", "-next", and
 "-pause-play") */
#ninja-slider-prev, #ninja-slider-next
{
    position: absolute;
    width:70px;
    height:140px;
    line-height:140px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-70px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url(images/navs.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    transition:width 0.5s, background-color 1s;
    color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0.4;
    font-size:14px;
}
#ninja-slider-prev {
    left: 0;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    background-position:0 0;
}

#ninja-slider-next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    background-position:100% -140px;
}

#ninja-slider-prev:hover,
#ninja-slider-next:hover         {
    width:110px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);cursor:pointer;}

/*pagination within the prev/next buttons*/
#ninja-slider-prev div {margin-left:74px;white-space:nowrap;}
#ninja-slider-next div {float:right;margin-right:74px;
    white-space:nowrap;}


#ninja-slider-pause-play { display:none;}

/* Other settings
-------------------------------------------- */
#ninja-slider h2 {
    position:absolute;font-size:100px;width:100%;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-weight:bold;top:20%;text-align:center;color:#FFF;
}

#ninja-slider h3 {
    position:absolute;font-size:50px;width:100%;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica, Arial;
    font-weight:lighter;top:20%;text-align:center;color:#FFF;
    padding-top:140px;
}

/*styles for mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #ninja-slider h2 {
        top:22%;
        font-size:40px;
    }

    #ninja-slider h3 {
        top:22%;
        font-size:20px;
        padding-top:60px;
    }
}

/* Usually you don't need to change the following settings
---------------------------------------------------------- */
#ninja-slider > ul
{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#ninja-slider-pager, #ninja-slider-prev, #ninja-slider-next,
#ninja-slider-pause-play
{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

#ninja-slider
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    padding:0;
}

#ninja-slider > ul
{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}

#ninja-slider > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I will do that and repost.

Comment: Don't repost, just [edit] this question.